# SharePoint List Subscriptions

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, alerts

If I have "Full Control" permission on a list, is there a way for me to see all the individuals who have an alert set for that list?

Some people in my department are better at managing their own subscriptions than others, and this is a question I have received from several team leads.  They want to be able to see and confirm who has alerts set up for a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to Site Actions > Site Settings > User Alerts, a drop down list with all of the users who have alerts set anywhere in the site gets displayed.  You can then select a user & click update - this will show you where in the site the alerts are for.

Unfortunately it doesn't give you the option to see all of the alerts for a particular part of the site.  So, you could easily answer "Does John have an alert set on my announcements?" but it would not be so trivial to answer "Who has an alert set on my announcements?"

Comment: FWIW, I believe this option is only available to administrators of the site collection.